# When parsing excel files, why doesn't encoding matter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

For my initial attempts at parsing an excel file in nodejs, I tried to read the file with the assumption that it was `UTF-8` encoded:

```
  var fs = require('fs');
  var excel = require('excel-stream');
  fs.createReadStream(__dirname + relativePathToFile, 'utf8')
    .pipe(excel())
    .on('data', console.log);
```

but this produced an error:

```
Error: j: error parsing /tmp/_1509140718263: Error: End of data reached (data length = 1910319, asked index = 1910332). Corrupted zip ?

    at /apps/node_modules/excel-stream/index.js:49:34
    at ConcatStream.<anonymous> (/apps/node_modules/concat-stream/index.js:36:43)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at ConcatStream.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at finishMaybe (/apps/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:511:14)
    at afterWrite (/apps/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:393:3)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:86:20)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Later when I ignored the encoding:

`fs.createReadStream(__dirname + relativePathToFile)`

Everything worked out fine.

This situation brings me to the question:

> When parsing excel files, why doesn't encoding matter?
>
> Is the default data read in as latin1 or binary?
>
> Who is responsible for properly decoding data which might have been entered in a non-latin language into the original excel file?

Comment: It doesn't matter because .xlsx files are not text files so 'encoding' is just not a sensible thing. It's not clear from your question why you assumed they are. The error itself tells you that your excel reader actually expects a zipped stream (i.e. the format is a zip compressed binary)

Comment: when using someone elses library, it's best to read their documentation - nothing in excel-stream documentation mentions text encoding

Comment: @pvg - please add your comment as an `answer` so that I can mark it as the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel `.xlsx` files are in the [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) format - a zip archive containing multiple internal files (typically XML, with their own encodings etc). As binary files they don't have text encodings and you don't need to provide one when opening them as a stream to pass on to your Excel parsing library. The error you got was the underlying library complaining it could not interpret the stream as a valid zip archive after you forced it to be decoded as utf-8.